# Is there a word for 'calling out to anyone who may respond'?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Is there a word for calling out in contexts like:

- if I am in a dark room and I call out "who's there?"
- if I am in a desert and I call out "is anyone out there?"
- if I am sending a broadcast over a communication channel to see who is on the line?

Broadcast might work but I am wondering if there is a more "human" word for this?

Comment: For the first two, ‘calling out’ seems the most natural phrasing for me, though it is of course not ideal for a broadcast sent over the radio, for example.

Comment: Simply "call" works quite well.

Comment: Marco??????????

Comment: ["Pig-Hoo-o-o-o-ey!"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig-hoo-o-o-o-ey)

Comment: "CQ CQ" is one I grew up hearing often, as my dad was an amateur radio operator. It's a shout-out for anyone on that band to respond.

Comment: To clarify: do you verb, noun, or both?

Comment: I had a noun in mind but either one works.

Comment: In some contexts you can call this a _ping,_ but I don't know that it would be universally understood.

Comment: What I like about ping is that its something that sonar detectors do, which is very evocative of this situation of "to my knowledge, I'm alone, but I expect that I am actually not, and I am going to find out." However in this context "ping" is more of a scan - I don't require an active response in order to detect a given presence, as I would if I were calling out to potential listeners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are phrases (and related verbs and nouns) that describe the first two such as **give a holler**

This is related to the verb *[holler](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/holler)*

> to shout or yell (something)

but it has a less excited quality, and is often used to refer to a greeting, and can even be used to convey *contact me*.

A similar term is **give a shout**. This also has a less urgent tone than the verb *shout*

These terms could be used to refer to electronic communication, but this usage is probably not very common. It has a bit of an oxymoronic quality (electronic amplification eliminates the need to *holler* or *shout*).

A related phrase specifically used on broadcast media is **give a [shout-out](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/shout-out_7)**

> a greeting, especially when someone on the radio sends the greeting to someone who might be listening

Another term commonly used for the electronic *shout* on a computer line to see if someone is there is **[ping](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ping)**

> to send a test message to (a computer or server) in order to check whether it is responding or how long it takes it to respond

Comment: As it happens, I was writing a program that translated certain network traffic to human-readable expressions, and was looking for a word that I could use as a translation for "010d0a" which is this device controller's phrase for "multicast request for all available devices to report their existence." Its sort of a "promiscuous ping" or a "to-whom-it-may-concern ping" I suppose. "Open-recipient ping"? "Recipient-agnostic ping?" I think shout is probably the best fit over all.

Comment: Interestingly, a google search reveals that Cisco offers something they call a "hoot and holler" network to enable fast propagation of information in such scenarios as the floor of a financial exchange.

Answer (score 2):

the word that I can immediately think of is

***halloo***

> a shout to attract attention, esp to call hounds at a hunt
>
> Used to catch someone's attention.
>
> To call out to.

(source: freedictionary.com)

Comment: Nice but very old-fashioned - and perhaps a suggestion of knowing that there's someone there, rather than of broadcasting one's presence to all and sundry?

Comment: Chris - I agree with that - however I thought just as you would use it when hunting, you might employ it when you are in a dark room or a desert. "Call out" probably is still the best as Janus remarks, but if you are looking for a single word....

Answer (score 2):

You can use

> **challenge**: *transitive verb* 2: to order to halt and prove identity *the sentry challenged the stranger*

or

> **challenge**: *noun* 2a : a calling to account or into question c : a sentry's command to halt and prove identity

from m-w.com

Comment: @terdon - Hmmm OK. I guess it could be used as a description of the first one ("who's there?") dependent on tone of voice it is said in. challenge definitely implies some degree of demanding a response over and above simple inquiry though.

Comment: Yes, I think it still could be a challenge if delivered in the right manner even if it turns out that no one is there to answer it. My original reaction to this answer was completely negative but I am coming round to it. To me "challenge" would indicate a certain attitude which may or may not be present based on the information in the question.

Comment: This is good but, to me, implies 1) a security context and 2) a certain directedness, as though there must be a specific recipient. "Issuing a challenge into the night" sounds right to me for the most part, but doesn't quite capture the "CQ CQ" (as LindaBrammer mentioned in a comment) connotation I was hoping to include.

Answer (score 0):

In all your examples, the person is ***Testing***.  e.g. for the existance of someone, for a listener, etc.

Answer (score 0):

After further thought, I would like to offer:

> **RSVP**: *abbreviation* please reply

It's a bit out of context, traditionally for a written invitation *to something*, but  I don't think it gets more direct than this.